Charts axis ticks are not completely visible
Charts axis ticks are not completely visible as something is drawn on the canvas over the ticks. It looks like this is a bug in Primefaces 12 but is there any workaround? Below are samples:

Here you can see most of the x-axis ticks are not visible completely

Please include a [mcve]

You can try to adjust the padding or Margins
$.jqplot('chartId', data, {
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            pad: 1.5, // Adjust this value

        },
    },
    grid: {
        drawGridlines: true,
        gridLineColor: '#cccccc',
        background: '#ffffff',
        borderColor: '#999999',
        borderWidth: 2.0,
        shadow: false
    },
});


Or you can rotate the labels
$.jqplot('chartId', data, {
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                angle: -30, // Adjust the angle as needed
                fontSize: '10pt'
            }
        }
    }
});




How do you do that using PrimeFaces?

Maybe share your code so I can help modify it ?

That's exactly what's wrong with this question!
